# How to set same speed to UIView animation

Tags: ios, animation, uislider

I want to set speed to my `UISlider`, to make it move more smoothly.

Here is how I am trying to animate it :

```
 UIView.animateWithDuration(6, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCurlUp, animations: { () -> Void in

            self.videoSlider.setValue(time, animated: true)
            if self.videoSlider.value == self.videoSlider.maximumValue {
                self.playerLayer.stop()
                self.playBigButton.hidden = false
                self.pauseButton.hidden = true
                self.playButton.hidden = false
            }

            }, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> Void in

        })
```

But it moves with a different speed on the beginning, middle and end.

Comment: Why do you use `UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCurlUp`?

Comment: What _is_ a `videoSlider`?

Comment: @dokun1 sorry just tested something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving your animation the option of `.CurveLinear`, like this:

```
 UIView.animateWithDuration(6, 
                      delay: 0.0, 
                    options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCurlUp, .CurveLinear],
                  animations: { () -> Void in

            self.videoSlider.setValue(time, animated: true)
            if self.videoSlider.value == self.videoSlider.maximumValue {
                self.playerLayer.stop()
                self.playBigButton.hidden = false
                self.pauseButton.hidden = true
                self.playButton.hidden = false
            }

            }, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> Void in

        })
```